# What would cause full body armor to return?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, armors

Many times in sci fi, the concept of full body armor has come up again and again.  Most famously in Star Wars where we see Stormtroopers wear white armor covering their entire body.

[image]

What I'm wondering is *why?*  Modern soldiers wear armor that only protects a small region of the upper torso and head to save on weight and have better mobility.

Why would a future military have standard issue armor that covers the entirety of the body?

Some assumptions:

- The material the armor is made of is light and strong enough that it does not burden the solider much, or at most requires assistance in either a passive/very minor assistive exoskeleton to operate with.
- Guns and projectile weapons over all are still a thing.
- Covers at least 75% of the body if not fully.  Nothing is stopping use from going the way of the peasant soldier i.e. focusing on head, torso, arms and hands protection.  Maybe leg armor too, if you're lucky.
- The soldiers wearing this armor are in a terrestrial environment.

[image]

Comment: `So why would a future military have standard issue armor that covers the entirety of the body`, especially when it literally *never* does any good?

Comment: Presumably, stormtroopers armor can also serve as a vacuum suit.

Comment: "So why would a future military have standard issue armor that covers the entirety of the body?"  In some sense we have that today - we just call it a tank (or APC, etc).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Not a vacsuit per in-universe explanations, but more akin to CBRN gear you might find a modern military using (plus of course the ideological aspect of making the force even more outwardly homogenous).

Comment: No time to write a full answer, so please steal this idea. Make laser weapons dominant over projectile ones. This is easy since they have the obvious advantage of not requiring ammunition. Then an armor made of highly reflective material is an obvious defensive response.

Comment: Just look at the modern US Army tactical gear. It effectively full body armor to a level equal or even more covered than standard full armors used in the past. They do tend to focus on the hazards typically encountered today. Not very protective against a heavy broad sword, but the odds of surviving a gun shot is better

Comment: Monsters. Think about radiation, genetic engineering, pollution...plenty of potential for mutation in the future if something goes wrong. Then, look at Monster Hunters. Such monsters are perfectly capable of attacking unarmored parts or dealing with armor, which would necessitate, better full-body armor.

Comment: There's an often overlooked nuance to body armor that civilians frequently miss - it's not intended to make the user immune to attack, but to increase their survivability and staying power. Grazing shots and glancing blows that don't bleed mean your effective fighting force retains it's numbers longer with fewer losses to shrapnel, infection, etc. Armor won't make you immune to an IED, but it CAN effectively reduce that device's kill radius.

Comment: If these soldiers frequently fight in harsh environments (high or low temperatures or pressures, for example) they will need heavy full body protection. EVA suits on the ISS are designed to be bulletproof (or micrometeor-proof), since conditions in orbit are so harsh.

Comment: Armour is designed to ward off perceived threats; that's all. Can you describe the actual characteristics of stormtrooper armour? Can you describe the threats the troopers actually face?

Comment: Storm trooper armors is designed not only to protect them but to make them intimidating to the general population.

Comment: Star Wars' Storm Troopers aren't a "future military" - they're from a "long time ago in a galaxy far far away" :)

Comment: Um, simplest answer: it makes extra actors reasonably interchangeable without ruining filming of the shot.

Comment: Riot armor is full body armor. So are hazmat suits. Armor isn't generic. It is tailored to the threats. Every armor piece you find in a museum will have been made with specific threats in mind to try to stop, slow, or deflect.

Comment: FWIW, stormtrooper armor is shown to have no practical purpose. It certainly doesn't stop standard weaponry as evidence by how easily they die when shot. First Order stormtrooper gear is explicitly said to not filter toxins. The only thing it's good for is to erase any expression of individuality, and to serve as faceless enforcers of an oppressive regime. It's 100% for show. I guess the question to you then is: does it has to be practical?

Answer (score 56):

**Environmental dangers**

Space is a dangerous place. You may find that you're more at risk of dying from radiation or lack of oxygen or heat than by being shot by the enemy. Sure you might get instantly obliterated if one of their ship artillery hits wherever you are on the ship but should you survive you want to be protected from dangers such as depressurization and lack of on-ship life support systems.

You will need to be protected from head-to-toe in order to be protected from most if not all environmental dangers, especially in space, which is what I'm assuming is the general environment of your setting by your use of storm troopers as example.

Comment: To some extent, if you knew your crew were all suited and self-sufficient, you would depressurise those areas prior to battle, to prevent enemy artillery from causing catastrophic decompressions or risking fires in those areas.

Comment: @Nij they do that routinely in the Honor Harrington stories.

Comment: Modern EVA suits on the ISS are designed to be literally bulletproof to protect from tiny, high-velocity bits of debris. The issue with duplicating these suits for a military application would be cost, as an EVA suit costs about $12 million.

Comment: @MarkPrice the main reason "an EVA suit costs about $12 million" is that they're made bespoke, and by hand, not mass produced.  Any endeavor which needed to outfit an entire military with something similar would quickly benefit from economies of scale.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman There's a limit to that economy of scale though.  You might be able to bring it down by a factor of 10, but that still puts you at a million dollars a soldier.  Even a factor of 100 puts it at 100k, which for the US army alone (480,000 active personnel) makes 48 billion dollars to kit out everyone.

Comment: @Graham Even if you assume that's the limit to the economies of scale (not supported by evidence), that's a fraction of the yearly budget of the US Army, and you don't need to outfit every person in a branch of the military with EVA-equivalents, any more than they currently outfit every person with a full set of the current body armor design.  If you want to see an example of economies of scale moving from bespoke construction to mass production, look at the launch costs of the Saturn V or space shuttle vs. the Space X Falcon 9.  That's far more than 2 orders of magnitude improvement.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman This is *space*. *Everything* will be astronomically expensive without some radical technological overhaul.

Comment: Bonus: If your soldiers are already suited up to some degree, why not reinforce it so that debris and scrapnel from that artillery hit is blocked at least, so  only the people directly in the zone hit take damage and the rest can get on with repairs asap

Comment: @Graham and if these sailors are in one of 3 interstellar-capable vessels and each have 10+ years of training PLUS a PhD to fulfill their complex jobs and are a billion lightyears away, then the 10 million per person extra are NOTHING compared to the expense of getting them where they're fighting or the expense of having enough replacement on standby.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman Those aren't examples of economies of scale.  The launch costs of the Saturn V or shuttle included large amounts of genuinely new R&D, which SpaceX could simply lift and run with.  They also include materials science and control systems design which were not available back in the day.  If you want to compare bespoke versus mass production, consider the cost of an Aston Martin against a Ford saloon.  You're looking at about 5x difference; less than 1 order of magnitude.

Comment: @Hobbamok But if you can justify any expense to protect your people, then economies of scale are irrelevant because you're willing to throw any amount of cash at the problem.   And then you're back to your $12 million EVA suits.

Comment: @KevinKostlan Nice pun ;-)

Comment: @Graham if you're going to sit there claiming that SpaceX didn't have to do any "genuinely new R&D", then of course you're going to end up with the fallacious position that the economies of scale resulting from mass producing the engines, tanks, and entire rockets somehow aren't economies of scale.  Ironically, you mention "materials science and control system design that wasn't available back in the day" without acknowledging that it was *SpaceX* who researched, designed, built, & tested those control systems, and did a lot of materials science design and testing.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman I'm not claiming that SpaceX didn't have to do new research. I'm starting as unarguable fact that their starting point (in 2002) was 45 years of experience putting rockets into orbit, 35 years of fly-by-wire electronic control, major conceptual advances in DSP maths and control theory, many orders of magnitude improvement in processing power, computer memory that didn't have to be hand-wired on ferrite cores, incredible advances in metallurgy, the entire existence of composite construction... And using all this to repeat something which had already been done.

Comment: @Graham I never made that economies of scale point. And even if we're back at 12 million suits: who cares in my scenario? Nobody. The cost of having replacement personnel on board are 500 million or more.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman sorry mate, but SpaceX didn't really do anything except apply known concepts in a way that was mass-produceable. They did - for a rocket - hardly any R&D in material science, design etc. Even the "landing and reusable rocket" thing is from the 70s or 80s

Comment: @Hobbamok You were replying to me discussing whether economies of scale were possible.  If you don't care about economies of scale, you're replying to the wrong person. :)

Comment: @Graham "...to repeat something which had already been done."?  Fascinating...  Show us all the orbital launch system prior to SpaceX which landed and re-used the first stage booster.  What's that?  You can't, because SpaceX was literally the first to do so?  Hmmm...  That would mean you just lied because you couldn't support your claims otherwise.

Comment: @Hobbamok "...the 'landing and reusable rocket' thing is fro the 70s or 80s".  Please show us all the reusable rocket from the 70s or 80s that was landed.  What's that?  You can't, because SpaceX was literally the first to develop a landable, reusable orbital launch booster?  Oops.  So much for your whole argument.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman Please show us why being reuseable or landable affects the ability to get a payload to orbit. Oops, so much for your non-argument. Have SpaceX done R&D, especially on landing? Of course they have. Did they invent putting payloads in orbit? Of course they didn't - literally every aspect of that was already invented by other people, and it's routine enough that schoolkids can get CubeSats into orbit on regular launches. And by the way, the Ryan X-13 jet prototype managed a controlled vertical landing in 1957.

Comment: @Graham so now your 'argument' is that if we ignore all of the R&D that SpaceX did with their rockets, then they did just repeated "something which had already been done", but you still can't name the orbital launch system with the landable, reusable booster that they supposedly replicated.  It was (and is) the reusability of the launch system which has driven down launch costs via the SpaceX Falcon 9 several orders of magnitude below that of the prior launch systems that you keep pretending they just copied.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman Less than a single order of magnitude, compared with prior launch systems. Have rockets been landed before? Yes, for 40 years. Have vanes been used to steer falling projectiles? Yes, for 60 years. (Dates as of 2002 when SpaceX started.) Sure, SpaceX needed to research how to put all this existing tech together into their rocket. But there is no technology in SpaceX which has not previously been done before. The only novelty is putting them all together. Which, sure, is a great achievement - but at no point have SpaceX created anything conceptually new.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTVL#History literally 2 seconds of google. Muskt isn't some kind of god, calm down

Comment: @Hobbamok, congratulations.  Your link demonstrates that my claim was correct, and yours was false.  It's been funny watching you try to alter your claim after the fact, and still fail to make even your revised claim true.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman ok clown

Comment: @Hobbamok, and there's the well-reasoned response of someone who is able to defend their position with facts.  /s

Comment: @Graham The limits to how much economy of scale can assist in the production of a given technology depend on the technology.  While a hand made car may be 5x as expensive as a mass produced car, something like a circuit board can take millions of dollars to design, a multi-billion dollar factory, days to set up the factory to produce the boards, and then pennies worth of material and a couple of seconds of time to actually make them.  So, you cant just use some arbitrary other tech to compare EoC savings for making a space suit.

Comment: @Nosajimiki For simple estimates, you absolutely *can* use arbitrary other tech to take an educated guess.  Since you mention electronics, that's a great example.  Making the bare fibreglass-and-copper board (which really isn't "pennies" for anything significant!) might be comparable to making the composite helmet shell, say.  Then the board needs components fitted, needs switches and buttons fitted, needs a box assembled around it, and so on.  Economies of scale make consumer electronics much cheaper, sure, but your 60" TV is never going to be "pennies".

Comment: @Graham No, electronics the size of a TV will never be "pennies", but the raw materials in electronics don't vary a whole lot.  The raw materials used in an iPhone 14 and a Samsung Gusto 3 are not all that different.  One costs ~\$500/unit to make the other costs ~\$10/unit.  The iPhone costs more mostly because the RnD and tools to make it are much more complex.  If Apple chose to produce, and could sell hundreds of billions of iPhones, then they would not cost a whole lot more to make than the Samsung Gusto 3, but the more complex you get, the more scale it takes for EoS to reduce overhead.

Comment: I just ran a cost break down on the actual materials used in a space suit, and it's only ~\$3000-3500.  The average soldier's equipment costs ~\$17,500; so, with enough EoC, you could get it affordable enough.  That said, most people don't realize just how much more it would be worth it to spend on soldiers, if more expensive and clearly superior technologies emerged.  The US military spends an average of ~1/2 a million dollars training each solider; so, even if EoS cant get you down into today's expected price range.  A \$100,000+ kit that improves performance enough would still be worth it.

Comment: @Nosajimiki If you want to be reductive enough to consider the price of a double-fistful of beach sand as the raw materials, then OK.  That doesn't contribute anything useful to the conversation though, because the difference in cost for electronics comes down to complex equipment needing complex construction processes.  Looking at the raw material cost of a few kilos of kevlar and aluminium is not a useful indicator for the cost to manufacture a complex item, any more than a car's price is based on just sheet steel.  That's where it's instructive to compare other complex manufactured items.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Since a space suit very clearly *is* a complex manufactured item, and even with mass production must always remain that way, comparison against other complex manufactured items is valid.  For comparison, a tonne of structural steel currently costs £1300.  A Mini Cooper weighs around 1.5 tonnes, but it costs £16,000 and not £1950.  And that's for something with relatively easily-automated production.  For reference on other things we wear, the world still does not have fully automated sewing machines.

Comment: The cost of a space suit has FAR more to due with RnD costs than production costs.  Milling and sewing all the parts by hand is not very labor intensive.  Only few thousand dollars at most.  The reason a space suit is so expensive is because it costs millions of dollars worth of research and countless prototypes to decide what it takes to make an effective suit... but with only ~20 space suits of any given design ever being produced, they have to include that RnD in the cost.

Comment: This would be like if they only made 20 minicoppers, but did all the RnD, engineering, crash testing, and product assurances they do for a production model vehicle.  While it would not take much more than £16,000 to make one, the price tag per car would be in millions.

Answer (score 39):

Body armor is designed to protect mostly against the type of bullets we use.

These bullets produce localized damage. They don't fly that fast. Some body parts are more vital than others. Armor is heavy and cumbersome. The enemy will aim for the center of the chest because it's a lot easier to hit than the head. So it makes sense to only put armor on the most vulnerable parts.

To justify full body armor, you'd have to change one of these parameters.

Remove the current rules of engagement and allow for poisoned bullets that kill you even if they hit you in the pinky finger... or white phosphorous, or explosive bullets... then damage is no longer localized, and most body parts become vital. In that case, you would need full body armor.

Change the enemies, for example give them acid for blood that sprays everywhere when shot.

Make flamethrowers legal! Everyone get an asbestos suit!

Fight in vacuum: any hole in the suit means a very bad day, so it has to be bulletproof everywhere.

Make aiming more accurate, for example robotic auto-aiming space pew-pew lasers that travel at the speed of light, or homing bullets that can reliably hit any non-armored part on a moving target. Then you need to armor everything.

Use the Space Shotgun instead of the space rifle. I mean, if you're shooting people inside a sci-fi spaceship you probably don't want to use .50 cal or armor piercing bullets that will go all the way through the ship and puncture the reactor confinement or just blow the air out. So you'd use space buckshot instead, which works better in close quarters anyway. If the enemy uses space shotguns that aren't armor piercing, you don't want a heavy thick chest plate because the spread of the shot means you'll get hit somewhere that isn't covered anyway. It would be better to have lighter protection and more coverage.

Comment: Look up frangible bullets for inside space craft.  Feel free to add that if you want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frangible_bullet

Comment: Frangible space buckshot!

Answer (score 31):

There exist already today full body armors: hazmat suits

[image]

In a scenario where the enemy can use biological, chemical or nuclear weapons, you want to avoid that those substances enter in contact with the body of the soldiers. The only solution is therefore to fully cover the body and leave 0 exposed surface.

Comment: True, but it's not exactly armour.  Per the question, that would explain the black under-suit, but not the white armour shell on arms and legs.

Comment: @Graham hazmat suits in that picture might be fine for post-combat cleanup, but are ill-suited for combat itself, where necessity of fast motion, sharp edges, enemy projectiles / laser beams etc. would quite easily make a holes in them or rip them, making them quite useless. So you would need white armor protecting that sealed under-suit.

Answer (score 19):

## One New Thing (Name Your Problem):

All you need to justify head-to-toe armor is ONE new attack form that requires armor to protect from it. It doesn't matter WHAT that
is, as long as the logical defense is armor. It doesn't even have to
be an attack currently in use - even knowing the enemy WILL use it if
you don't defend against it will require everyone to be armored. And
a suit isn't enough, because the slightest breach of the suit will
kill you.

- **SONIC WEAPONS**: Sound weapons are developed so lethal or debilitating sound waves cripple the nervous system. Only adding vibration-cancelling protection to all parts of the body keeps out the sonic attack. If armor can be made to absorb shockwaves, this can even apply to reducing ubiquitous blast effects.
- **NBC**: Nuclear, biological, and chemical weapons mean chemicals, radiation and disease are able to penetrate to a man not covered everywhere. Chemicals can include things as humble as irritants. Only constant isolation protects you. Anthrax can be everywhere and new strains made to overcome the best immunity.
- **INCOMPATIBLE ENVIRONMENTS**: Alien worlds, ice-cold arctic winters, deep ocean, hydrochloric acid atmospheres, space, the list goes on and on.
- **KILLER MICRODRONES**: Tiny robots are everywhere, and out for human flesh. The armor needs to be strong everywhere to keep these evil things from finding a vulnerable spot. And perhaps you need to periodically douse in acid or flaming gasoline to kill off the things as they accumulate on your gear.

That list could go on all day. But in addition, there are other reasons to completely protect your troops.

- **YOUR COST PER MAN IS INSANELY HIGH ALREADY**: Each trooper requires vastly costly training and equipping to make him effective, or the men who can fight are wildly rare. Maybe 1 in 100 men is immune to mind control, or 1 in 1000 is psychic. Maybe you need a PhD to operate the linear accelerator cannons in all the possible situations. Or the effort to deliver one soldier to the battlefield costs a billion dollars (teleporters, interstellar travel). No cost compared to that is too high to assure each man is able to fight to peak efficiency.
- **EVERYBODY USES POWERED EXOSUITS ANYWAY**: Every man needs to operate completely independent of the supply chain or the equipment (weapons, life support) they use is too heavy to move in without an exo-suit. If you can haul 10 tons of gear, what's half a ton of ablative projectile & heat resistant plating amongst friends?
- **PROJECTILE-RESISTANT OPPONENTS**: If the enemy (zombies, super-armored guys, shock-resistant aliens, robots) is resistant to small penetrating projectiles and the tissue shock that goes with it, they might close to melee range without being substantially slowed. Against that alien's fire breath, acid spit, claws and swords you're going to want to have a full-body suit of armor just like the ancient knights did as you incinerate the still-moving chunks of your opponent.
- **INDEFINITE SURVIVAL**: Your battlefield can't guarantee your soldier supplies. Your suit recycles CO2 into sugars, amino acids and oxygen. It's your food, clothing and shelter. Every bit of you is covered because every bit of anything that comes out of you is recovered. It's like a Fremen stilsuit and space suit hazmat suit and body armor all in one.
- **SHRAPNEL**: If your battlefield is full of high-explosive weapons blowing everything everywhere to tiny flying bits of shrapnel, the primary threat becomes either vaporizing (not much you can do about that) or getting hit with tiny projectiles that can cripple your soldiers. Without head-to-toe armor, no soldier will last more than a few minutes before they have so many minor wounds that they can no longer function. VR goggles tied to sensors let you see through the smoke, VR hearing means you aren't deafened by the blasts, respirators mean you can breathe when the air is full burning gasses. You can walk through the burning buildings, absorb some of the shockwaves from explosions, and so on.
- **MEDICAL**: Your suit is a walking medic. It detects injury anywhere on the body instantly, administering stabilizing chemicals and immobilizing crippled limbs. It tourniquets at the sight of bleeding, inactivates pain locally to allow a soldier to withdraw or keep fighting.
- **ZOMBIE SOLDIERS**: In the event your soldier dies or is crippled, the suit can activate the exo-suit and continue to operate. It will move the soldier to a medical facility or fire on opponents without the appropriate transponders. Dead soldiers can be 'ordered' into suicide attacks to draw enemy fire or carry bombs to destroy enemy positions. How terrifying is that?
- **YOUR ARMY CONSISTS OF WEALTHY FOOLS**: If your army is a group of poorly trained volunteers but supported by a nation of great wealth, then the sons and daughters of the elite are walking into a gunfight without the skills they need to live. Maybe your advanced society has forgotten how to fight wars as wars disappeared. Maybe it's a bushido thing where the elites lord it over the commoners but have an expectation that they be willing to fight and die for the nation. The solution? Those ridiculously expensive suits of armor that protect the fools from the consequences of their own actions. Once they figure out how to fight again, they're used to the $2.5 million dollar gear and don't know how to fight without it.

Comment: 10/10 list. Also you can easily combine almost all of them with each other so there are multiple reasons.

Answer (score 18):

**Homogeneity.**

Who are the officers?  Who is telling people what to do?  Who are the high value targets?

If soldiers have their entire bodies concealed it is harder for an enemy to figure out which soldiers warrant more attention.  Additionally, if you are a soldier, uniforms of this sort will conceal the fact that some of your fellow soldiers are aliens, or robots, or resurrected zomby soldiers.

Comment: This could work well especially if the suits also contain some visor thingy that allows you to discern between your own soldiers and commanders - to the enemies everyone's the same, to you everything's clear

Comment: this will of course cause the same level of confusion among your own soldiers, who's orders should I be listening too, who do I look to for orders,  who is specialized in X, who has clearance for this, Who is actually a soldier and not an imposter, who is slacking off or gone missing, oops followed the wrong squad again...

Comment: Why do you need full body covering for this though?  Simply dress everyone in the same fatigues (as modern armies do), and ban lower ranks from saluting on the battlefield.

Answer (score 12):

### You've already answered your question

> The material the armor is made of is light and strong enough that it does not burden the solider much, or at most requires assistance in either a passive/very minor assistive exoskeleton to operate with

If the material is so light and unencumbering, then there would be little need to leave out armour pieces for weight or mobility. And so, given that an armoured bodypart is more resilient than an unarmoured part, it would be a no-brainer to cover up the entire body

Comment: This does give you the question: why would you not use the saved weight to add MORE protection to the torso and head instead of adding protection on other bodyparts as well? After all if you can choose to either double the protection on your chest and head or add protection to the rest of your body... what would be a better choice? Losing a hand or leg might not seem fun but if it increases the odds of both surviving and being able to continue fighting after a hit there is a good argument not to go for full body protection.

Comment: @Demigan  Modern body armor that only covers the head and torso is just as heavy as a full plate armor was in the medieval period.  Knights were not just protected against kill shots, like modern soldiers, they were protected from nearly every manner of debilitating attack.  A modern solider is still quite easy to disable if your spray them with a few bullets, but full body armor that can stop nearly all small arms no matter where hit could not just keep you alive after being sprayed by bullets, but keep you from being injured or removed from the fight.

Comment: @Nosajimiki well thats the point: FIRST you would add enough armor to the torso and head that you'll survive just about anything and THEN you might consider adding armor to other places. The alternative is "if we add more armor it becomes so thick it limits mobility so we add the extra armor on the rest of the body".

Answer (score 8):

**Armor must be effective against the primary threat.**

Platemail went away because it as guns become sufficiently advanced, they cease to offer sufficient benefit frequent enough for its cost and burden. That doesn't mean armor went away entirely, they just might not be in the form depicted in Star Wars. Kevlar vests, ballistic armor, etc. do exist and are frequently worn.

**1) Material science advance sufficiently that body armor can sufficiently protect against the most common threat.**

There can be multiple methods armor mitigates damage, and depending on your world the most common source of damage need not be kinetic in nature.

- Direct (As conventionally known)
- Ablative (Reduces or Eliminates the material from the incoming attack)
- Absorptive (The armor takes away the incoming attack from the weaerer, perhaps absorbing an electrical charge, or perhaps taking all the impact force in the wearer's stead)
- Dispersive (Maybe in your world bullets became obsolete and energy weapons became dominent, the armor disperses the energy harmlessly across its surface)
- Insular (Is the primary source of damage through biological/chemical warefare, or even electrical or heat?)

**2) The environment or operational conditions warrants it.**

Maybe your characters live on a hazardous planet. Maybe rockslides are common, toxic gas, heat waves, etc. Maybe they live under the sea. Armor isn't limited to combat use. Real-life Exoskeltons will probably see heavy duty use in the form of mining etc. before combat use, that doens't mean your soldiers cannot equip such an armor for non-combat purposes while on active duty. Once it is established that operational conditions warrants such an exosuit, they might start adapting it for combat utility based on field experience, but such a suit's priamry function will be to fulfill operation conditions.

Answer (score 6):

### Psychology + Uniform

Even light plastic armor with some kevlar under it goes a way to protect from discontent civilians. At least if the solders are in compact group. Also it improves their morale, as they see brave friendly solders around, even if they are scared inside. It protects from inconvenient scratches, or in case of falling from speeding motorcycle. Even if soldier is wounded, enemy cannot say how much or even wheter - so until really disabled every unit looks like fully functional.

Full body armor looks intimidating, may have demon-like face and does not show, if it contains scared newbie or hardened special unit veteran (but suggest the later). As such units are usually used against civilian "rebels" in big number, this looks make half their work done - week civilians take cover, run away scene and only "hardened criminals" are left to oppose such power demonstration.

Also having the same armor makes good uniform, to recognize your man from opposition fast. And small and cryptic distinctions make easy to be spotted by trained eye and recognize to fast evaluation of who is from which unit, which specialisation or which level of authority.

Plus it is easy to mass-produce such armors and have soon big army where only few are really trained, while it looks, like all are top specialist. Good for evel overlords as well for film studia :)

Comment: of course scary masks also makes it harder to deal with non-combatants, which is a bigger and bigger part of a soldiers job and full body armor concealing injuries also makes it harder to assess and more importantly treat injuries,

Comment: As evil overlords I rule by fear, not love :) Anyway today police use similar tactic against demonstrations (just black variant, body armor and the rest hidden, also anti-riot shields - not pink uniforms with unicorns/Hello Kitty). In near future I suppose at least simple monitors to state, if and what inner part of armor was damaged - so what is possible injury. If it is light exo-skeleton plastic type, it can be designed to strip as fast as classic uniform, if not faster. (Compare downhill skying-shoes - no knots and laces prone to ice, but just flip few clips and the feet is free).

Comment: For less evil overlords / friendly rulers (or goverments) it is still good as anti-riot, fast overtaking units and power demonsrtation, which is to take the land/place and establish basic war ruling. Second wave will be in contrast much more human looking powers (say like normal police+byrocrates) set to establish civilian rules, all evidence, healthcare, taxes, hospitals etc.. and vissible improvement from that scary first wave - old good sugar+whip tactic.  (And third wave civilian looking undercover agents / inteligecy members )

Answer (score 6):

### Armor Simply Needs to Become Lighter

Full body armor is always better than partial armor as long as it can meet the following two criteria:

- It must stop all common threats when hit.
- It must not be so cumbersome as to make one combat ineffective.

If you make your armor too thin trying to get full body coverage, it will not stop any common attacks; so, it is just waisted weight, but if you make it too thick or too heavy, then you can not move in it which also makes it useless.

The only reason we do not still use full body armor is that modern armor is not good enough to cover the whole body and stop a common riffle round without also being too heavy.  To fully cover a solider today with riffle armor would mean loading him down with over 100kg of body armor; so, to compromise, we use armor that weighs just as much as a suit of medieval plate armor did, but we focus that armor only on the most critical and likely places to be shot.  If you were to improve armor enough that you could stop most common riffle rounds with a full suit of armor that still weighs 25kg or less, then full body armor would very quickly come back into common usage.

Alternatively, if you were to improve a soldier's carry capacity to over 100kg using cybernetic or biological augmentation, then you might also see an increase in full body armor, but... this may be less likely since a higher carry capacity also means you can carry a bigger gun; so, higher caliber weapons may also become the norm simultaneously eliminating the advantages of more armor.  So if you were to try to solve this problem with super strength instead of lighter armor, you need to make sure that the main threat will still be normal soldiers packing things in the 5.56-7.62mm range.  So super solders have to be the exception, not the rule, for this solution to work.

Lastly, the problem we see a lot in sci-fi (and a lot of fantasy actually) is that common attacks go right through full body armor.  When you look at something like a storm trooper, full body armor makes no since because every common hand gun seems able to go right through the armor and kill them, even when hit in the chest which should be the most armored part.  However, if you instead envision something like the [Kull from Stargate](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Kull), you then have something that makes a lot of since to see full body armor on. Since their armor is actually effective at stopping most common weapons, they can walk right out into a hail of bullets taking shots to the arms, the legs, the face, the chest, and everywhere else.  This means they can focus their whole effort on shooting the enemy and not have to waste any effort on not getting shot.

Comment: Agreed, the only reason we don't make full body armor today is full body bullet resistant armor would weigh hundreds of pounds.

Comment: @John And because modern militaries have _other_ units that can fill the role of [armored cavalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armoured_cavalry). They just aren't knights anymore.

Comment: @Ray what dos heavy Calvary have to do with it, every soldier would wear full body armor if it was light and effective. Also in the past infantry  also wore full body armor.

Comment: @John I think what's he's saying is that if tanks or vehicles did not exist, you would inevitably end up with a small number of specialized, very heavily armoured troops to fill the role even if body armour was otherwise too heavy for regular troops.

Answer (score 5):

### Laser weapons

Their armour looks shiny..

Modern armour material can be **reflective**, that is why it may return.

In Star Wars, the stormtroopers have a light weight, *reflective* white armour.

Edit:
In real life, strong laser beams will damage mirrors, same would happen to armor. A shiny armor would be most effective compared to clothes, when the angle of the laser light is not perpendicular to the surface. In any case, the comments below are justified.. body armor against laser should be thick and (very) heat resistant as well !

Comment: Not really. Any weaponized laser would burn the surface of even the most reflective mirrors we can currently conceive. While a fraction of the laser will be refracted and has a high chance of blinding anyone seeing the scatter the amount of the beam that is absorbed by the reflective surface will burn it and reduce its reflectivity for the rest of the beam, which burns it more until its as reflective as non-mirrors. Unless your mirror is in excess of 99.999% reflectivity or the laser is outperformed by normal bullets its not going to be useful.

Comment: That said, armor can be very effective thermal insulator; so, even if it does not reflect the laser, it can block the heat of the laser to prevent harm.

Comment: Laser on the battlefield will not always hit perpendicular. I think reflectivity would at least help reduce the energy to be absorbed by the armor. Clothing would not protect at any angle. Thanks both for the input, I've put an edit.

Comment: @Demigan You don't use a mirror.  You use a gazillion mirrors.  Take tiny, tiny retroreflectors and a binder to fuse them into solid pieces.  Yes, a powerful enough laser can burn it, but it still bounces most of the beam back at the shooter until it's burned all the way through.

Comment: @LotenPechtel explain that one to me? That doesnt seem to solve the problem as the retroreflectors would still burn and absorb most of the beam anyway just like a mirrored surface would. Because that is the problem: the first part of the beam would hit, and the part of the beam that is absorbed burns the surface/retroreflector causing it to absorb more of the rest of the beams causing it to absorb more and by the time the beam ends (which likely takes a fraction of a fraction of a second) the surface/retroreflector has absorbed most of the beam's heat, which is the point of a laser weapon.

Comment: @Demigan Assuming your target is not moving and a robot is holding your laser steady,  even a low grade mirrored surface reflects more light than it absorbs, retro-reflective tape used for safety gear reflects more than half the light that strikes it. that means your enemy needs weapons at least twice as powerful for the same effect, AND they have to worry about blinding and flashback damage.. Also a surface that charred would be great, many material become incredibly good thermal insulators when they char.

Comment: @John thats just it: most of the light will still be absorbed. Your retro reflective tape will lose its reflectivity in the first fraction of a second as the heat burns it and then absorb 99+% of the rest of the beam/pulse. Thats quite literally what I already mentioned in the first comment. As for charring, the heat would vaporize part of the material and cause a small explosion and shockwave, creating a hole where the rest of the beam can go in (and the reason lasers would use many many pulses in a fraction so it does not heat up debris)

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject (despite the answer) but it seems *laser mirrors* come with a damage threshold https://www.actonoptics.com/products/ndyag-mirrors

Comment: @Demigan actually vaporization often has the opposite effect creating a better insulating layer, the vaporized material which does not effectively transfer heat. this is what ablative shielding is.  you seem to be talking about a far more powerful laser than anything that could be man portable, and you also seem to be assuming the laser is hitting the same spot at a high angle which is unlikely.

Comment: @Demigan ablative materials, microscale mirrors, and high insulation materials are already be researched and used to protect drones from lasers. https://www.sbir.gov/sbirsearch/detail/164279/

Comment: @John ablative material and high insulation are something completely different than what we discussed and I quite literally said you would need a reflectivity above 99% for it to work, which dielectric mirrors are apparently. So everything you said remains wrong (like 50% reflectivity working). Also the article that led you to that link mentions that it only increases the time before a burn. Thanks for the article though, that at least is interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Secret police or collaborators from an occupied country.

Occupying another country is hard. Doing it with just my troops from home? Now that's tough. So I need some locals to help out, but the local population isn't on-board yet with my leadership and I don't want my people hassled when they're off the clock.

What better way to protect them than to conceal who they are with full body armour and face coverings?

Answer (score 4):

The armor incorporates a powered exoskeleton.  It allows the soldier to carry the armor, and its power supply, without increasing their burden.

It will also allow the soldier to carry additional ammunition and supplies and even heavier weaponry.  It could also include environmental protections (possibly including heating or cooling) that would not be practical for a soldier without such a suit to carry.

Comment: Started my answer quite a while ago, but didn't get back to the page until now to press Submit.   An hour after @ThisIsMe submitted his answer.

Answer (score 3):

*I'd say that the previous answers have covered most of the reasons why armor could return.*

**Effectiveness against commonly-used weapons**

To add to the above, if the materials from which armor is made prove to be sufficiently effective against "short range" weapons (i.e., machine guns, pistols, shotguns, grenades) they would normally encounter during combat, then you'd have an argument for them to make a return.

Intuitively, as no sufficiently-light AND comfortable armor can protect from a hit to the face or hands, there is no reason to inconvenience soldiers with it, but if technology allowed for a face cover or "armor glove" that would save you from it, and be comfortable enough as stated in other answers, then military forces would definitely incorporate it.

**Effectiveness against new weapon types**

If the materials, alloys or fibres from which armor are made are better suited to stop or deflect new types of weapons (i.e., beam weapons), such as Star Wars' armor, which is supposedly "designed to disperse the energy of a blaster bolt and insulate the wearer, lessening injury", then full body armor would make sense.

This ties to the previous: if, for example, beam technology became cheaper, safer, more economically efficient or better overall, then militaries will switch to beam weapons and full body armor might be the most reasonable counter.

Answer (score 2):

It's already returning.
E.g. this is the Sotnik infantry armor that Russia is developing, planned to be done 2025(picked it as an example, because it looks the most sci-fi ish, there are plenty of others):
[image]
https://taskandpurpose.com/military-tech/russia-sotnik-combat-armor-development/

You must remember, that body armor didn't go away due to ineffectiveness as such, e.g. 17th century plate was quite effective at stopping muskets from all but point blank range and would have been for a couple centuries more, until muskets went away, the word bullet-proof comes from the literal proof that it would stop a bullet that the purchaser required the armorer to provide in front of him:
[image]

However, due to the large quantities of high quality, tempered steel required to do it, it was too expensive to mass-equip the new armies of the modern age and due to the fact that no armor would do squat against cannon anyways, the cost-benefit equation worked out to: heaps of cheap unarmored troops > a small number of armored troops.

The tech for at least somewhat effective 3/4 armor has arguably existed since the 80s, but it was too expensive for the mass armies of the time.

Now, all militaries, including the Russian one are moving in the direction of a relatively small number of well-trained(hence valuable) troops, so the cost-benefit equation has shifted back to armor.

Comment: Or alternatively, the cost of manufacture goes down due automation or some other new advancement.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated: the main reason that soldiers today only wear light partial armor is due to weight. The encumbrance of full-body armor outweighs the benefit of full protection.

To get back into full armor, one or both of that must change: either full body protection must become a definite benefit, or the weight of the suit must be reduced (or both).

One way to do this is with some variation of *power armor*. Things like exoskeletons that do exactly that are already in development.
Such a suit will at least support its own weight, making encumbrance a net-0, and if it increases carrying capacity or walking speed, it gets to be a complete benefit.

This can be combined with benefits that other posters mentioned; like protection from environmental hazards (poison, or the vacuum of space)

Answer (score 1):

### The balance of Offence vs Defence swings the other way

Right now, the problem is that an armor that can stop a bullet in its tracks is expensive, heavy, inflexible and generally only good for one or two hits with low-calibre weapons.

Weapons technology has vastly outstripped personal body-armor to the point where we no longer defend against direct attack.
Instead, we defend against secondary effects. Shrapnel, debris, glancing hits. Things that would cripple but usually not instantly kill.

This, incidentally is the ideal-case for a Storm-trooper's plasteel armor-plate.

Remember the prison-block in A New Hope? Remember how fast the fire-fight turned it into a storm of debris, shrapnel, smoke and alarms?

Those storm-troopers might die in a single direct-hit, but they shrugged off the shrapnel caused by blaster-fire hitting walls and blowing up nearby hardware like it was nothing. And they started shooting before the smoke from breaching the doors had cleared.
Those helmets have all kinds of respirators, filters and optics to let them fight in hostile environments where a lesser-equipped person would be blind, choking and probably dead.

We also never see a clear over-penetration of the stormtrooper armor. Plenty of burn-marks and troopers falling over, but plenty of times a trooper was clearly still alive after being hit. For example one trooper fell off a catwalk when directly-hit and was clearly screaming as he fell.

One imagines that the storm-trooper armor is actually excellent as a defense against lighter blasters (such as their own E-11 carbines and hand-blasters) and most of the storm-troopers we see shot are actually alive, just knocked on their asses by the impact and burns they just received.

So back to the offence/defence tradeoff.

Stormtrooper armor is very light-weight. The clue is in the name "Plasteel", a lightweight polymer with properties reminiscent of steel.
If it weighs anything like say.. ABS, or a thermally resistant resin, it could be very lightweight indeed.
An armor that defends against most non-military small-arms well enough to prevent the trooper being killed in many/most cases, and can turn a military-grade glancing hit into something survivable, provides NBC protection, can see through smoke and gases, shrugs off shrapnel and acts as highly functional riot-gear?

Sounds great.

Now imagine what that would look like in real-world modern terms.

A suit of body-armor that can stop pistol-caliber hits entirely (even if the wearer gets knocked off their feet), and can turn a killing blow from larger caliber weapons up to .50 cal into something survivable.

We don't have the technology for that right now, but if we did, we might see the return of the suit of full body armor.

Answer (score 0):

Your military strategy emphasizes sheer numbers and brute force over everything else. Remember that the Stormtrooper example is based on what is essentially a limitless clone army. Not all of them will require this level of full-body protection, but some will, and the full body armor is standard issue to all. It's the mass production of troops, without any exceptions or differences whatsoever, right down to every element of gear.
Each branch of the U.S. military has its own standard working uniform, and each MOS has a relatively standard issue of gear all its own; for instance, a Bosun's Mate must be equipped with knife, lighter, and marlinspike at all times.
This is just the same, except there's only one MOS throughout the entire force.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read Seven Eves by Neal Stephenson. Potential spoiler:

Combat in that universe takes place mostly in space habitats. Conventional weapons are not ideal in that environment.

So they developed a kind of weapon that shoots tiny robots that avoid penetrating habitat structures. When landed on humans they would crawl around to find an opening in the suits and wreak havoc.

Full body armor could definitely be useful in this scenario to prevent or slow these small robots from entering their suits *and bodies*.

Answer (score 0):

**Armor doesn't have to stop incoming projectiles from infantry rifles (or bigger)**

Up until very recently, there were no helmets that were rated to stop rifle rounds. They were meant to stop shrapnel and fragmentation. That's not to say that a rifle round wouldn't bounce off a steel helmet at the right angle. The same with early flack jackets. The amount of material required to make something bulletproof also made it impractical for infantry to run around with. After all, they are called $Flak$ jackets because they were issued to bomber crews to protect them from German Flak. It took another 20 years for infantry to be issued body armor.

Infantry kit is becoming heavier and heavier. According to [this](http://www.45thdivision.org/Pictures/General_Knowlege/combatload.htm) the fighting load of an infantryman in 1944 was about 75 pounds. The last time I went to the field, my load was 112 pounds. Eventually, the amount of kit an infantryman is required to carry will dictate that he needs some mechanical assistance. An exoskeleton will react A LOT poorer to a piece of shrapnel than the squishy thing wearing it. Think of the scene in Iron Man 2 with the prototype Iron Man suits from the other countries failing.

In short, the suit of armor would likely be designed to protect soldiers fully in the upper chest and head, with lesser protection to prevent unessasary mechanical injury everywhere else.

Comment: This seems to be a frame challenge, but it’s not properly worded as such

Answer (score 0):

Let's make two changes:

First, a weapon already under development:  Grenade launchers with rangefinders and spin-fused rounds.  You take the range to whatever the enemy is hiding behind, you take the range to whatever's behind the enemy and set the grenade in between.  The grenade launcher sets the fuse to a certain number of spins and you fire just to the side of whatever the enemy is behind.  The grenade goes past and explodes beside your target.

Second, improved armor.  Lightweight material that can repel grenade fragments.

Now, any soldier that doesn't have such armor is very vulnerable to such side-attack grenades.  Note that you won't see many such grenades used because the armor stops them--so long as they are available it makes the enemy wear the armor.